# What does gs protocol mean?

Tags: json, uri, speech-recognition, google-cloud-platform

I'm playing with [Google Speech Recognition API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/)

After a successfully [Getting started](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/getting-started) I'm trying to understand and made some changes in this first example but I don't know what "gs" protocol is and how to set it to use my own audio file.

sync-request.json

```
{
  "config": {
      "encoding":"FLAC",
      "sample_rate": 16000
  },
  "audio": {
      "uri":"gs://cloud-samples-tests/speech/brooklyn.flac"
  }
}
```

I tried to change gs protocol to http protocol but doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`gs://` scheme is used for identifying resources stored in [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage).

Answer (score 71):

You can access the file that you mention as follows:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/cloud-samples-tests/speech/brooklyn.flac
```

So, if you create/upload your own file in Google Storage -- like I'm doing now while testing the same API you are using-- **the "equivalence" is the following**:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/
```

**translates to**

```
gs://
```

**and viceversa**.

I have no idea why Google doesn't explain this clearly.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

This is what Google's API docs says:

https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rpc/google.cloud.speech.v1beta1#audioencoding

> URI that points to a file that contains audio data bytes as specified
>   in RecognitionConfig. Currently, only Google Cloud Storage URIs are
>   supported, which must be specified in the following format:
>   gs://bucket_name/object_name (other URI formats return
>   google.rpc.Code.INVALID_ARGUMENT).