NSInvalidArgumentException, in Swift?
I'm trying to play an audio(mp3) that is uploaded to Firebase.
This AudioManager class caused an error at player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url) when I called the playAudio() function.
class AudioManager {
    static let instance = AudioManager()
    var player: AVAudioPlayer?
    
        func playAudio() {
            guard let url = URL(string: "gs://quranburma.appspot.com/x.mp3") else { return }
            do {
                player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
                player?.play()
            } catch let error {
                print("error playing audio. \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        
        func stopAudio() {
            player?.pause()
        }
    }

The error says:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSTaggedPointerString getCharacters:range:]: Range {0, 12} out of bounds; string length 2'
*** First throw call stack:


Strange error. I'm wondering if the gs:// is really supported... Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38806490/what-does-gs-protocol-mean or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20478369/how-do-you-get-or-generate-a-url-to-the-object-in-a-bucket maybe with "full classic URL"?

@Larme, the error changed after replacing gs:// with https://storage.googleapis.com/ saying "No such file or directory".

How did you get that URL? If you're using FireStorage, I guess they have a method to get the HTTP url from that GS URL, no? Is that URL "public"? Did you try to put your "bucket name"?

@Larme, yes they have a method and I'm trying it now. I got the url from firebase console directly.
